# Как парсит https url json на jquery

Tags: jquery, json, url, https, парсер

Дорогие гуру помогите не как не пойму как мне парсить https url json через jquery сделал так:

```
var myurl = "http://hws.m.taobao.com/cache/wdetail/5.0/?id=538910539466";
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: myurl + '&callback=?',
  }).done(function ( data ) {
      alert(data);
  });
```

Но у меня выводит ошибки: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

P.S спарсил этот url через curl php но ответь очень долгий, мне кажется если пробовать через js думаю ответь будет быстрым.

Comment: через js получится только в случае если хост будет кидать заголовок "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * " те разрешено всем(ну или конкретно твой домен вернет, откуда делаешь запрос). иначе сделать ajax запрос нельзя. делай через php

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
var myurl = "//hws.m.taobao.com/cache/wdetail/5.0/?id=538910539466";
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: myurl + '&callback=?',
      }).done(function ( data ) {
       alert(data);
    });
```